# How to get ipv6 address in flask?

Tags: python, networking, flask, ip

I'm tring to get the client's ipv6 (if present) or ipv4 address whenever my api end point is hit. Here's the code:

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/ip", methods=["GET"])
def ip():
    return jsonify({'ip': request.remote_addr})
```

But currently, only the ipv4 address of the client is returned. Is it possible to get the ipv6 address of the client ?

Answer (score 3):

You can start your app specifying an ipv6 address

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello there %s" % request.remote_addr

app.run(host='::')
```

For `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` this will yield

> hello there ::ffff:127.0.0.1

And output

```
 * Running on http://[::]:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2018 10:06:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And for `http://localhost:5000/`

> hello there ::1

And

```
 * Running on http://[::]:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
::1 - - [09/Aug/2018 10:11:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```